# Paperclip Processors are not loaded in Rails 3.0.0rc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I just started using [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and have a custom processor. I have put the new processor in the correct location `RAILS_ROOT/lib/paperclip_processors` But, it does not get loaded.

The reason for not loading, is that `Rails.root` is nil at the time `paperclip` is loaded. I've tested this by putting explicit code into the `paperclip.rb`

```
puts "What is Rails.root? #{Rails.root}  #{Rails.root.nil?}"

if defined?(Rails.root) && Rails.root
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.expand_path(Rails.root), "lib", "paperclip_processors", "*.rb")).each do |processor|
    require processor
  end
end
```

Which will print out `What is Rails.root true`. And the processors are never load.

Is there a fix or work around for this? The work around right now is to just add a require for our processor. but that doesn't seem right. Here is the work around (our processor does tar'ing), in the model that will be using the processor, just require it at the top:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/paperclip_processors/tar.rb"

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :adzip, 
                :styles         => { :targzip => {:processors => [:tar], :format => 'tgz'} }
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to include the paperclip_processors directory

```
module Trunk
 class Application < Rails::Application

 Paperclip::Railtie.insert

 # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)  
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/paperclip_processors)  
 end
end
```

But I'm still having a problem where it's not loading the class within cropper.

```
Expected /Users/jspooner/Dropbox/active/local.active.com/rails3/trunk/lib/paperclip_processors/cropper.rb to define Cropper
```

cropper.rb

```
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if crop_command
        crop_command + super[1..super.length]
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        " -crop '#{target.crop_w.to_i}x#{target.crop_h.to_i}+#{target.crop_x.to_i}+#{target.crop_y.to_i}'"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: when you add an `autoload_paths` it expects that to be the root of the modules for the classes. Since you put in the paperclip directory, it skips that part of the module. So it expects  just class Cropper, instead of  module Paperclip class Cropper.

Comment: Thanks christophercotton.  To further elaborate his comment, you'll need to create another folder named "paperclip" under the "paperclip_processors" folder.  The reason is, as chris stated, is that the hierarchy of modules encapsulating the defined classes you're including should match the folder structure.  So since the Cropper class is under module Paperclip, you need folder paperclip to match module Paperclip.  And since you're specifying path "lib/paperclip_processors" in your config, it all needs to go under that.